# open-ended paths in topology

Tags: general-topology

In topology, paths are always defined as images of continuous functions from the unit interval $I$. However, it also makes sense to define "open ended" paths, e.g. as continuous functions from the *real line* $R$ to a space. And furthermore, the image of any continuous $f : I \to X$ is also the image of a function $f' : R \to X$ obtained as $f \circ g$ where $g$ is a surjective continuous function from $R$ to $I$.

Is the "open ended" variant also defined and used in textbooks? That would correspond to using compact Hausdorff spaces with no non-cut points as domains ?

Comment: You might be interested on the homotopy lifting property, that's the most similar thing I know to what you're explaining.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_lifting_property